# Display locations from a database on a map issue

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

Hi i am getting customer location from database to display it in google maps
the code works fine but the problem is if the last customer location column is equal to null the map wont load and dose show any pins

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var markerArray = [];
    window.onload = function () {

        var t = self.setTimeout(function () {

            var size = $('.LocationLabel').length;
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                var markers = { locationLatitude: "", locationLongitude: "", Cust_Name: "", Address: "" };
                var Location = $('.LocationLabel').eq(i).text();
                var CustName = $('.Cust_NameLabel').eq(i).text();
                var Address = $('.AddressLabel').eq(i).text();
                markers.locationLatitude = Location.split(',')[0];
                markers.locationLongitude = Location.split(',')[1];
                markers.Cust_Name = CustName;
                markers.Address = Address;
                markerArray.push(markers);

            }

            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers.locationLatitude, markers.locationLongitude),
                zoom: 12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            for (i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
                var data = markerArray[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.locationLatitude, data.locationLongitude);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.Cust_Name
                });
                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.Address);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
</script>
```

```
  <asp:Label ID="lbl_Location" CssClass="LocationLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Location")%>' />
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_CustName" CssClass="Cust_NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Cust_Name")%>' />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Address" CssClass="AddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address")%>' />
```

markers data-source

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
DataTable dt = this.GetData("select * from Customer");
rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
rptMarkers.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Why not handle null with some default location better give them a default lat/lng or else don't show customer who don't have location. e.g. `select * from Customer where location IS NOT NULL `

Comment: thanks for the solution